# Using two procedures to make simple calculations with OUT and IN parameters, PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We're assigned to create two procedures in Oracle's 11g PL/SQL language that will make a simple calculation.
The assign is as follows:

> Create two procedures, where the first (`a`), will receive two values with IN-parameters, it'll then send the values to procedure `b`, which will calculate and display the result.

I've looked around the net and read books about this, but I can't get it to work. I'm met with error codes constantly, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm not even sure it's possible this way, but it's difficult finding answers to it.

Here's my code:

```
SET serveroutput ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_a
(number1 IN NUMBER, number2 IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  proc_b(number1, number2);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_b
(number1_proc_a IN OUT NUMBER, number2_proc_a IN OUT NUMBER, result_proc_a OUT NUMBER)
AS
result_proc_a number;
BEGIN 
  result_proc_a := tal1_proc_a + tal2_proc_a;
  dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || result_proc_a);
END;
/

CALL proc_a(4, 6);
```

If anyone has the slightest idea why it doesn't work, I'd appreciate the help greatly! The error message I'm met with is:

```
PL/SQL: Statement ignored. Object proc_a is invalid.
```

And:

```
Package or function %s is in an invalid state
```

**EDIT:**
With help from user Sagi, I got it working! Thanks :)

Comment: Declaring an input variable as IN OUT is ok? Also, it looks like you declare result_proc_a at the start as an out, so why are you trying to define it again ?

Comment: Oh, geez... You're right. That solved my problem, haha. I must've gotten blind from all that code! Thank you, it works as expected now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points to look at:

- You have a duplicate variable name *result_proc_a* in *proc_b*: it is declared as the third parameter and as a local variable.
  You should remove the local variable declaration.
- It would be better to declare the procedures in the opposite order. *proc_a* depends on *proc_b*, so first create *proc_b*. That way *proc_a* will not be in an invalid state after its creation.
- Although parameters can be `IN OUT`, there is no need for the first two parameters of *proc_b* to be `OUT`. By removing `OUT` you allow the possibility to call *proc_b* with literal numbers.
- Depending on the environment you use, it might not work to do a plain `call`. In that case use a `begin end` block, which works always:

```sql
    BEGIN
        proc_a(4, 6);
    END;
    /
```

---

I see you got the problem solved already. I just leave this answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this . Hope below snippet helps you. Only one thing i suggest here
>   is use pls_integer in place of NUMBER if you have very heavy computation
>   part in the procedures.

```
SET serveroutput ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_a
(number1 IN OUT PLS_INTEGER, 
number2 IN OUT PLS_INTEGER
)
AS
resl_proc_b PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  proc_b(number1, number2,resl_proc_b);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_b(
    number1_proc_a IN OUT PLS_INTEGER,
    number2_proc_a IN OUT PLS_INTEGER,
    result_proc_a OUT PLS_INTEGER)
AS
  tal1_proc_a PLS_INTEGER:=0;
  tal2_proc_a PLS_INTEGER:=0;
BEGIN
  result_proc_a := tal1_proc_a + tal2_proc_a;
  dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || result_proc_a);
END;
/
```